# Oauth / OpenID with Gitlab as provider

Tags: oauth, gitlab, artifactory, openid-connect

Does anyone know if it is possible to override the scope sent by Artifactory when trying to use Gitlab (On Premise) as the OpenID Connect Provider?

Currently, Artifactory is sending `&scope=openid%20profile%20email` as a url parameter, but Gitlab can only handle `&scope=openid%20read_user`. If I manually edit the URL, it works logging in, but that is just a hassle. Artifactory should really have a way in the UI to set / override the scope :(

Any help here is appreciated.